# How to keep the packages intact on RStudio installed on Google Cloud VM

Tags: r, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, docker-volume

I launch R studio VM instance from Google console. I install many packages from the R studio. Now once I stop the VM and restart it, the packages get deleted. 
SO again I have to install the packages afresh.

I got so articles on web which talk about creating an image after installing packages then creating VM on top of it.

But I want to use the same VM everytime.

Somewhere I got to know that this is due to restarting of docker. 
Can you just tell what changes I should make to the console so that the dockerfile won't get restarted. So that I don't have to install the packages everytime I start the VM.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are a bit confused by the tools you are using.

First of all **if** you are running your application on Docker it is normal that each time you exit it you "lose" every change you have done to your machine and a Docker container is not a virtual machine.

If you want to proceed with the docker container solution there are basically these possibilities:

- If you are interested to [preserve the change you have made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585028/i-lose-my-data-when-the-container-exits) to the base image (notice that you should follow this each time you want to "save") you could read this Stackoverflow answer.
- You might want to look at docker volumes if you you want to persist the data in your container. Visit https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/. The docker documentation is a very good place to start, but also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189091/stop-vm-with-mongodb-docker-image-without-losing-data) question can be useful.
- When you use docker run to start a container, it actually creates a new container based on the image you have specified.

  ```
  docker ps -a
  docker start f357e2faab77 # restart it in the background
  docker attach f357e2faab77 # reattach the terminal & stdin
  ```

However are you sure that the best way to proceed is to run a docker container and not on a normal Google Cloud Plaform instance?

Comment: Thank you
But when I create a VM in google cloud it automatically attaches a docker. Is der any way to stop this. I want to use the persistent disk to behave as normal disk of my laptop/

Comment: Just tell me a way to use Rstudio on google cloud the way I use it on my PC. I followed this(http://code.markedmondson.me/launch-rstudio-server-google-cloud-in-two-lines-r/) to install RStudio on VM. The only problem is that the installed R packages get deleted once I restart the VM.

Comment: Since you are not really familiar with Docker at the beginning it could be a bit tricky to understand how it works and how you should proceed to make your changes "persistent". I would suggest you either reading a bit the documentation and the Stackoverflow questions I sent you to understand it better or to go for a normal installation on a virtual machine that you can handle in a easier way. There is this post showing you how to do it step after step https://askubuntu.com/questions/862403/install-the-lastest-version-of-rstudio